# Can I change the default currency symbol in Excel 2016 for a single workbook

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel-2016, currency-format

I'm using Excel 2016 on MacOS High Sierra. I'm based in the UK, and so my global default currency symbol is £. I'm creating a new workbook with forecasts for a European operation, so in that workbook I want the default currency symbol to be €, so that I don't have to change all the cell formats manually. Is there any way to do this for just one workbook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I do not have the Mac version of Office on which to test my suggestions, but all are central enough to Office that they should work virtually the same on both Mac and Windows platforms.*

Excel uses your system settings to determine what the currency button does by default, but it doesn't actually have a default currency.  In the number formatting group, rather than clicking the currency button (which will use your system default) you can click the drop-down arrow next to it to choose the Euro instead.

[image]

If you are doing this a lot and the extra step is inconvenient, you can always temporarily change your system currency settings then restart Excel.  This way the default for the currency formatting button will go to the Euro automatically.  **This will not change existing files' currency settings.**

If instead, you are trying to use an existing file which was created using the Pound and you want it to change all the currency fields to Euros, you can do a find and replace on the cell formatting.  In the find and replace dialog box, clicking the **Options** button will allow you to select a format to search for.  The easiest way to select the formatting is to use the **Choose format from cell...** option, but this may include additional formats besides just the currency.

[image]

Once the original format is selected, in the Replace with box, you can choose a new format and select a new currency of the Euro.

[image]

Completing the replace at this point should find all cells formatted with Pounds and replace them with Euro formatting.  Be sure to change the **Within:** box in the Find and Replace window to `Workbook` if you have more than one sheet here that needs this change.

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem where a single workbook would always try to show Euro symbol whenever a number was inserted as currency format and would default to the euro symbol when manually formatting currency. The behaviour was particular to that workbook. Other workbooks would take the computers currency format (£).

I eventually figured out that in that one workbook the issue was with the "Style", the normal style was formatted as Euro, I could easily change it to £ as I wanted. So that would be one way you can format a single workbook to be in Euro.

Hope that helps anyone with that problem

Answer (score 2):

For me personally, Peter's response was the better. Being located in the US, my system's Currency was set to the USD ($) but my excel default currency was the Euro (€). To change it I had to change the currency "Style".

1. On the Home tab, find the "Styles" group in the ribbon.
2. Find the "Currency" style.
3. Right click on it and select "Modify".
4. Click the "Format" button at the top.
5. Select the Currency symbol and format you want. If you can't find what you want, scroll down to "Custom" at the bottom and select your preferred formats or create your own.

Answer (score 0):

Just highlight the entire page and change currency on the Home tab.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This does not seem to be an improvement on previous answers. How do you change the Currency symbol from one type to another on the home tab. Please elaborate.

Answer (score -1):

The best solution for Mac users: Quit from the Excel, go to System Preferences > Language & Region >  Advanced > Currency (Also you could change the decimal sign from “,” to “.” or vice versa)

Comment: How does that make the change for just one workbook without changing the default, as requested?

Answer (score -2):

If you're using this a lot like me you can change your default currency.

Go to control panel
Region
Additional settings
Currency tab:change currency to your favorite one € (copy paste )
or leave it blank using space

Comment: The question is about how to change the default just for one workbook. I already knew how to change the global default.